# Equivalence between limit and convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f:A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be an accumulation point of $A$. The following statements are equivalent:

$(1)$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=L$.

$(2)$ For every sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in $A \backslash \{ a \}$ that converges to $a$, the limit is equal to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_{n})=L$.

This property is not so very difficult, but I just want to know if my proof is correct, as I did not explicitly use the fact that $a$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

$\underline{Proof:}$

$(1) \rightarrow (2)$: Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=L$. Take a random sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in $A \backslash \{ a \}$ that converges to $a$ and take a random $\epsilon > 0$. Seen as $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, we know that we can find a $\delta > 0$ so that $\vert f(x)-L \vert < \epsilon$ for every $x \in A$ for which $\vert x-a \vert < \delta$. As $(x_{n})_{n}$ converges to $a$, we can find a $n_{0}$ so that $0< \vert x_{n}-a \vert < \delta$ for every $n \geq n_{0}$. Then will also $\vert f(x_{n})-L \vert < \epsilon$. So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_{n})=L$.

$(2) \rightarrow (1)$: Contraposition: Suppose that $lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) \neq L$. This implies that we can find a $\epsilon > 0$ so that for every $\delta > 0$ there exists an $x \in A$ for which holds that $0< \vert x-a \vert < \delta$ and $\vert f(x)-L \vert \geq \epsilon$. We can thus construct a sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ in $A \backslash \{ a \}$ so that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$: $0< \vert x_{n} -a \vert < \frac{1}{n}$ and $\vert f(x_{n})-L \vert \geq \epsilon$. The first inequality implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} = a$ while the second inequality says that $(f(x_{n}))_{n}$ cannot converge to $L$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: In the second implication you should take $\delta=1/n $.

Comment: Oh yes indeed! That mistake slipped in when I was typing by copying from my notes.

Answer (score 1):

In proving $(1) \rightarrow (2)$, in the last line it should be
$$0<|x_n-a| <\delta $$
for every $n\geq n_0$. The reason for first strict inequality is that $x_n \in A\setminus\{a\}$

The second implication is correct.